# HerokuApp Node.js express get TCP

Tags: node.js, heroku, express, tcp

Using Node.js express, I have a herokuapp that will app.get, app.post and app.all all response received.

Basically, I have a device that I can send SMS to and device will send TCP to a DNS but I'm not seeing any response in console.log.

Can someone please offer a solution or help?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Confused on what exactly is the issue you're trying to troubleshoot, as you haven't provided any code - just the basic infrastructure you've implemented.

Answer (score 1):

Only valid HTTP requests will route properly to your app running on Heroku.  You do have the option of using the HTTP/1.1 upgrade header to upgrade your connection from HTTP to TCP: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/http-routing#protocol-upgrades